# does tensorflow-serving or hosted Google ML allow for data preprocessing with 3rd-party libs when making online predictions? (Python 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

I have many tensorflow models which make use of 3rd party libraries (i.e. Gensim) to preprocess data prior to training and evaluation. This same preprocessing needs to happen when querying the model to make predictions.

If using either tensorflow-serving or the hosted Google ML solution, can I bundle 3rd party libs and a custom preprocessing step along with the model, and have either of the two serving solutions run it? Or, if I want to use 3rd party libraries, do I have to preprocess the data client-side? I have not come across any examples of this.

Just to be explicit - I know you can do server-side preprocessing using tensorflow's libs, I'm specifically interested in the 3rd-party case.

Comment: It looks like you can [write custom Servables](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/custom_servable), although it only mentions doing so in C++ (which doesn't help much in using Gensim).

Answer (score 1):

As far as the ML Engine is concerned, I don't see how this would be possible. Models deployed there need to be in the [SavedModel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md) format. This doesn't include any Python files for example where you could run custom processing. In contrast the training job that creates the model [can include custom dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview#packaging_your_trainer).